# How to add RecyclerView in xml in android Lollipop

Tags: android, xml, android-5.0-lollipop

I have updated my android SDK with Android 5.0 (API 21); I have also updated Platform tools and Build tools.

I am getting `The following classes could not be found:
- android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView (Fix Build Path, Edit XML, Create Class)` error after adding RecycleView in layout xml file.

My layout xml file looks like follows:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.androidlintro.MainActivity" >

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/hello_world" />

  <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</RelativeLayout>
```

can anyone tell me what's going wrong. Why I am getting this error, even after downloading complete set of software (new SDK, build tools, platform tools etc)

Note: I am using eclipse IDE

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the Android Support Library is included in your project.

In Eclipse: Right click on Project -> Properties -> Android

Then add the Android Support Library to the build path.

Then clean the project and build.

Comment: yeah its added. appcompact_v7 project is added as library by default

Comment: I have cleaned my project but while cleaning appcompact_v7 I am getting error "Cleaning selected project encountered problem"

Comment: Are you adding it as a JAR or as an included project in the workspace? See http://developer.android.com/tools/support-library/setup.html# for more info.

Comment: Now I am following the link you have provided In step 4 we have to import appcompact_v7. I have imported it but the project contains error

Comment: res->valuesv21->style_base.xml contain "error: Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 
 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'" at <style name="Base.Widget.AppCompat.ActionButton"
           parent="android:Widget.Material.ActionButton">
    </style> position

Answer (score 0):

### ***ECLIPSE***

If your problem is not solved or for future readers , here is the answer:
From android sdk manager download Android Support Library first.

Go to this location and copy .aar file from here

X:\android-sdk\extras\android\m2repository\com\android\support\recyclerview-v7\21.0.0

Then rename it as .zip file then unZIP it then find classes.jar file , rename it with some proper name like 'RecyclerView_v7.jar' Then copy the that .jar file in you project library. Add it to build path then restart eclipse so that it can be instantiated (not necessary but i had to do this).

Answer (score 0):

For Android Studio:

1. Select: File -> Project Structure... -> Dependencies
2. Click the "+" in the upper right corner and choose "1 Library dependency"
3. Search for "com.android.support:recyclerview"
4. You will see the current version of the library. Slect it and click "OK"
5. Gradle will sync and you are ready.